# Google Play Console - Search terms for play store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I submitted my first Flutter app to the Google Play Store using the Play Console. The app has been approved, but if I try to search by it's name "Roster Me On", it doesn't find it. But if I search by typing "rostermeon" it finds the app.

How do I set search terms for my app. Is this done in the Play Console or in my Flutter project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the search term is not configurable, it mostly depends on how you build your store listing page. There are [some recommendations](https://appradar.com/academy/app-keyword-optimization/implement-keywords) that you can do, some from the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/store-listing.html):

- Use strong assets, including your app title, description, icon, feature graphic, screenshots, and video with **high repetition of your keywords**
- Provide accurate categorization to help Google Play promote your app properly
- Test different keywords for your listing page
- Customize store listings and tailor your marketing messages to highlight key features and keywords for your app
- Localize your app store listing for users in different markets around the world

Check out [this official](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en) Q&A from Google. I'm sure it will help you a lot to boost your app's attention

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing pretty much all of this. The app title is mentioned about 5 times in the title and description. I'll try to refine.

Answer (score 1):

Other people can correct me if I'm wrong.

This has nothing to do with your flutter code or on the Play console. This is how the Play console search algorithm works. Since you just launched your app and I assume it's not having a lot of traction, it is hard to get listed, given that your app name is ambiguous.

When you give the query `Roast Me On`, it has 3 words. Thus it's open to a lot of combinations of search results. But if you search `roastmeon` it's one word and it obviously has lower combinations to go through.

To improve this odd, Promote this app on social media. Ask people to rate it. The more traction your app gets, it is easy for you to get listed in search results. Also, add relevant keywords and use high-quality assets. The more Professional your app looks, it is definitely an advantage.